# Creating a popup window in ASP.net to get user input

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

I am creating a web application, and I need to create a popup to accept two fields (maybe more) of input from the user.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use modal popup extender provided by Microsoft
[Have a look at it](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx)

Or you can use Jquery for this
[Have a look here](http://geekswithblogs.net/vladimirl/archive/2009/12/20/jquery-simple-modal-plugin.aspx)